# I am building QGIS 2.6.1 from source code on windows 7, 32 bit and after successfully building all projects I get this error

Tags: qgis, python

Couldn't load PyQGIS.

Python support will be disabled.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named qgis.core

Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
2.6.1-Brighton 'Brighton', exported

Python path:
['C:/OSGeo4W/./python', u'C:/Users/Awet/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/Awet/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGeo4W/./python/plugins', 'C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\OSGeo4W\bin', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL',